# Sorting multidimensional array on different keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a load of folders and I use `DirectoryIterator` to get them into a multidimensional array. The outcome of this is something like this

```
array:10 [▼
  "SomeTitle" => array:2 [▼
    2018 => array:3 [▼
      "February" => array:4 [▶]
      "January" => array:1 [▶]
      "March" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
    2017 => array:11 [▼
      "February" => array:9 [▶]
      "January" => array:12 [▶]
      "March" => array:9 [▶]
      "September" => array:9 [▶]
      "June" => array:8 [▶]
      "December" => array:12 [▶]
      "October" => array:8 [▶]
      "July" => array:10 [▶]
      "April" => array:8 [▶]
      "August" => array:10 [▶]
      "May" => array:10 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```

So I have the main key, followed by year, then month, and then some other data.

What I am trying to do is organise the data by year and month.  So 2018 should always be first.  I then need the months to be organised in month order.  At the moment, I am passing the array to this function

```
function sortArray($arr) {
    ksort($arr);

    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $arr[$k] = $this->sortArray($v);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

I dont think I need the ksort as this seems to put 2017 first.  When I run the above, I get the following

```
array:10 [▼
  "SomeTitle" => array:2 [▼
    2017 => array:11 [▼
      "April" => array:8 [▶]
      "August" => array:10 [▶]
      "December" => array:12 [▶]
      "February" => array:9 [▶]
      "January" => array:12 [▶]
      "July" => array:10 [▶]
      "June" => array:8 [▶]
      "March" => array:9 [▶]
      "May" => array:10 [▶]
      "October" => array:8 [▶]
      "September" => array:9 [▶]
    ]
    2018 => array:3 [▼
      "February" => array:4 [▶]
      "January" => array:1 [▶]
      "March" => array:1 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```

So everything is basically in alphabetical order.  Is there any way to change this so the year starts with newest to oldest, and the months are in calendar order?

Thanks

Comment: Smarter solution will be adding numeric keys instead months, then simply reorder by number and replace number with months' names if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`uksort()`](https://php.net/uksort) to check manually:

- if the keys is a numeric value: sort naturally
- if the keys doesn't match with [`strtotime()`](https://php.net/strtotime) sort with [`strcmp()`](https://php.net/strcmp) (It could be better to check if the key is equal to a "predefined" month name instead of checking `strtotime() === false`.)
- else sort using `strtotime()`

Code:

```
function sortArray($arr) {
    uksort($arr, function($k1, $k2) {
        if (is_numeric($k1)) return $k1-$k2 ;
        if (strtotime($k1) === false) return strcmp($k1, $k2);
        return strtotime($k1) - strtotime($k2);
    });

    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $arr[$k] = $this->sortArray($v);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
$array = sortArray($array);
print_r($array);
```

Outputs:

```
Array (
  [SomeTitle] => Array (
    [2017] => Array (
      [January] => Array()
      [February] => Array()
      [March] => Array()
      [April] => Array()
      [May] => Array()
      [June] => Array()
      [July] => Array()
      [August] => Array()
      [September] => Array()
      [October] => Array()
      [December] => Array()
    )
    [2018] => Array (
      [January] => Array()
      [February] => Array()
      [March] => Array()
    )
  )
)
```

Here is a working [demonstration](https://eval.in/978919).

Answer (score 2):

Numeric keys corresponding to the month would make more sense, but to do it with the names:

```
function sortArray($arr) {
    krsort($arr);

    foreach ($arr as $k => &$v) {
        if (is_array($v)) {
            array_multisort(array_map(function($m) {
                                          return date('m', strtotime($m));
                                      }, array_keys($v)), $v);
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

You want `krsort` to sort in reverse, then map the array months to get the month number and sort the original on that.  Pay attention to `&$v`.

You could just use this instead of `date`:

```
return strtotime($m);
```

Comment: `date('m', $m)` with `$m` containing a month name will issue an `E_WARNING` and return `false`. You probably wanted a `strtotime()` in there.

Comment: @salathe: Thanks edited. I posted without testing so may be other issues :-(